# How to draw a line on android tic tac toe game over wining pattern

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-image, tic-tac-toe

I have an sample android app for tic tac toe game.How to draw a line or paste a line image after winning over winning pattern(it is good if it is animated)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use view to show line and give background to it whichever color of line you want give width and height for line dimension.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/vFareUnderline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:background="#ff141414"></View>
```

Comment: Such as if patern is like that if ((c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0)
                || (c[1][2] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0)
                || (c[1][3] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[1][2] == 0 && c[1][3] == 0)
                || (c[2][1] == 0 && c[2][2] == 0 && c[2][3] == 0)
                || (c[3][1] == 0 && c[3][2] == 0 && c[3][3] == 0)
                || (c[1][1] == 0 && c[2][1] == 0 && c[3][1] == 0))

Comment: If u want to complete code i Will update my question

Comment: you can pre create this lines and initially  set its visibility to gone then whichever row to want to draw line set it visibility to visible

Comment: I am also thinking that...plz give a sample if possible.because there is some problem in drawing  diagonal line and putting the lines in each wining condition..